# What's wrong with this php mail code?

Tags: php, if-statement

```
elseif (empty($name) || (empty($email) || (empty($phone) || empty($message)) {
header( "Location: $contact_error_page" );
}
```

I get a parse error. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Something went wrong with those parentheses, look closer.

Comment: The most wrong thing with this "php mail code" is that it's not about mailing at all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about simple debugging and will not be of use to other users.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using many [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) functions, you can use one [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) (BTW, isset and empty are not actually functions. But this is out of the scope). The difference is slight, but IMHO it vastly improves readability.

```
if (...){
  ...
} elseif (!isset($name, $email, $phone, $message)){
  header( "Location: $contact_error_page" );
}
```

This way you will not have problems with parentesis.

Comment: `empty` and `isset` behave differently. Compare their corresponding results with `$a = '';`

Comment: yeap, I pointed this out that the difference is slight. Also because the question is not about the difference there is a link to the manual to read about this small difference. The main point is to show how to fix a code and make it readable.

Comment: "how to fix a code" by changing its behaviour. I really like it. You could propose to remove those lines as well. It would also "fix" the code and make it more readable.

Comment: the only difference is in handling false variable (and the ones that are casted to false). I am not sure that this is really important for the author, and instead of posting yet another answer about parenthesis I am showing another solution, which works a little bit different. This is up to author to decide if he needs to this behaviour or no. And I highlighted the difference. You are free to propose your solution with removing these lines

Comment: `isset($name, $email, $phone, $message)` returns `true` only when **all** variables are set. But in OP code `||` is used which will return true if at least **one** variable is not empty.

Comment: Also, you've missed closing bracket in `} elseif (isset($name, $email, $phone, $message){`

Comment: BTW, sorry, in my comment (at least one variable is not empty) I said wrong. I mean "is empty", not "is not empty".